# Microsoft Graph is returning html error (411 - content length Required) - but same request works using Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am making a web request using FileMaker's insert from url script step to the Microsoft Graph API. Here are the details of the request:

**URL**
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{emailaddress}/messages/{messageid}/move](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bemailaddress%7D/messages/%7Bmessageid%7D/move)

**Headers:**
-X POST
—header "Content-type: application/json"
—header "Authorization: Bearer {Token}

**Data**
{"destinationId":"{folderid}"}

**Microsoft returns the following error:**
HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.

When I try the same request using the Microsoft Graph Explorer, it moves the file as expected. "content-length" is not required in the Microsoft Graph Explorer request.

**Considerations**

1. I am sure the Token, MessageId, and FolderId are accurate.
2. I can get interact with the API using other endpoints in FileMaker
3. I have tried adding a "content-length" in the header, but it makes no difference